# Visual Studio log file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, logging

My Visual Studio 2008 Professional gave me the following error:

> An error has occurred in the
>   application. For more information
>   please see the log file.  Its path is
>   listed in the About box.

Riiight.  I went to the About box, and there is nothing about a log file.  And the System Info button has so much information, that I can't even figure out where to look for information on the location of a log file.  I tried the find, using 'log', and finally gave up -- there are too many 'dialog' and other false positives found.

So, where is that log file?

Visual Studio 2008, version 9.0.30729.1 SP; MS .NET framework version 3.5 SP1.

Comment: If you take a look at the [faq], you'll find that *software tools commonly used by programmers* is allowed here.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) of the `/Log` command line switch:

> If `LogFile` is not specified, two files
>   will be written to the current user's
>   non-localized application data folder.
>   The non-localized application data
>   folder for Visual Studio can be found
>   from the `APPDATA` environment variable.
>   For example, for Visual Studio 2008,
>   the folder is
>   **`%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0`**,
>   where `%APPDATA%` represents the value
>   in the `APPDATA` environment variable.
>
> The two files are, by default, called
>   `ActivityLog.xml` and `ActivityLog.xsl`.
>   The former contains the activity log
>   data and the latter is an XML style
>   sheet which provides a more convenient
>   way to view the XML file. To view the
>   Activity log in your default XML
>   viewer (e.g. Internet Explorer)

You will probably have to run `devenv` with the `/Log` switch for these files to be created. Visual Studio doesn't seem to log anything by default.

Comment: Ah, so unless I turn on logging to begin with, it will claim that the error is logged, but it isn't.  I don't find any ActivityLog files, so I'm guessing there is no logging (and thus no telling me where the log files are, either.)

Comment: The information about the XSL file and Internet Explorer is very helpful! I already knew how to create the IDE log file, but not how to properly view it. The log file uses colours so it's kind of easy to spot warnings or errors. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

The solution mentioned above is misleading. The error message you mentioned basically originates from an Add-in caled VMDebugger.
The location of their log file is available on the about box of the add-in.
The path looks like this

> C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\vmware-\vmware-vsid-2.log

I found the following entries in the log

```
6/4/2015 13:55:38: VMware Virtual Debugger loaded successfully.
6/4/2015 14:03:03: ERROR: pControls->get_Item(CComVariant(itemName), &pCtrl)
6/4/2015 14:03:03: An error occurred in .\Connect.cpp at line 8782. Error code is 0x80070057.
6/4/2015 14:03:03: An error has occurred in the application. For more information please see the log file.  Its path is listed in the About box.
6/4/2015 14:03:03: ERROR: pControls->get_Item(CComVariant(itemName), &pCtrl)
6/4/2015 14:03:03: An error occurred in .\Connect.cpp at line 8782. Error code is 0x80070057.
6/4/2015 14:03:03: An error has occurred in the application. For more information please see the log file.  Its path is listed in the About box.
```

**Additional info: Visual studio 2010 logs are available at**

> %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ActivityLog.xml %APPDATA%
>   resolves to “C:\Users\*user*\AppData\Roaming”

Answer (score 0):

Although I've tried to do with Sunil approach, it didn't work on my machine. So I tried to remove the following folder 
`C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Service Fabric Tools`

After this, I uninstalled all the previous and current Service Fabric installed on my machine and reinstall the Service Fabric for 2017.

Seems it's now working.