# Lost shared code reference in Universal Apps

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Anyone know why when I reopened Visual Studio **my reference to the shared project is no longer referenced** and when I try to add the reference back manually I can't do it. I did not remove the shared project to begin with.

I only have **SignalR** as referenced if that'll make any difference.

[image]

**Update**

Here's the [link](http://www.speedyshare.com/nyWyB/ActivityLog.xml) if anyone is interested for the Visual Studio logs

Comment: Any logs? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809430/visual-studio-log-file

Comment: @steve Logs doesn't seem to show anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a new `Universal apps` and compare the `.csproj`. I edited the existing `.csproj` and added this back. It worked but still doesn't explain why it disappeared.

```
<Import Project="..\UBelt.WindowsUniversal.Shared\UBelt.WindowsUniversal.Shared.projitems" Label="Shared" />
```