# Where can I find log installation file?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have some trobels to install visual studio 2013 on windows 10.

I want to read log file installation but I can't find it, 
I was looking for him in **C:\Program Files (x86)** but I didn't find anything.

My question where is log installation file stored?

Comment: it is stored in temp folder under **C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio log file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809430/visual-studio-log-file). Yes, the duplicate is for VS2008, but the location of the log file did not change between versions.