# Where's the log file for the SSRS Report Designer tool in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

When I preview my report Visual Studio Report Designer gives this error message, "Data retrieval failed for the subreport 'Subreport2', located at: /reportname.  Please check the log files for more information."  Where might I find the logs?

I found lots of answered questions for the location of the production logs on an SSRS server, but none for the Report Designer client.

Comment: have you had a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809430/visual-studio-log-file

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Under the path %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0 I found an ActivityLog.XML last updated in 2015.  Perhaps Report Designer logs errors elsewhere.

Comment: @BillVo did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: @TabAlleman I don't recall finding the answer.  If I was starting to look today, I'd use Visual Studio 2017 with Windows' Resource Monitor and/or Process Explorer to identify the file as it's written.