# Visual Studio error : could not start Visual Studio due to an error : System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I was working on Visual Studio 2019 which was working fine, but all of a sudden I start facing `RemoteInvocationException` from Visual Studio and everything stopped working (Build, Run, everything). I tried to uninstall and re-install Visual Studio and from then on, I've been facing this issue. Does anybody have any experience what may I be missing?

I tried all the basic cleanups, re-installed it multiple times including full installation, it's on my office laptop and I need to get it fixed instantly.

Whatever I have tried so far have given only this error:

[image]

Please help!!!

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/183206/could-not-start-visual-studio-due-to-an-error.html

Comment: already tried it, didn't work for me :)

Comment: From this [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/757606/streamjsonrpcremoteinvocationexception-the-followi.html), please confirm if there are related settings need to loaded and run when starting visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

The next step you should be taking is looking at the Visual Studio log file during startup.  This should provide you more insight to what the root cause of the problem is, and then you can put your attention onto solving that problem.

This other stack overflow question has a good answer that summarizes this:

[Visual Studio log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809430/visual-studio-log-file)

From there, if the issue is more complicated, you could post more detailed information about the particular issue.  But you may find it straightforward to fix once you find information from the log.